# Insert data from database to google chart codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert data to get sales report from two table into google chart. I have tried `join` query in `model` page, but the result is `No Data` in pie chart div.

Data from table sales is like below

```
id |    person_name  |      sales_id     |     status
 1       Michael                2                 1
 2       Daniel                 2                 3
 3       James                  2                 1
 4       Ricky                  1                 2
 5       Martin                 1                 3
```

The data from table status is like below

```
id |        status        |       color 
 1       Meeting                 #f00630
 2       Presentation            #f2478f     
 3       Proposal Sent           #170303       
 4       Invoice                 #7cb342 
 5       Lost                    #fe0725
```

I need to insert data `status type`, `total status (in number)`, and `color status` into google pie chart based on `sales id`. I need to change data which I write manually like below

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Type', 'Total'],
      ['Meeting', 2],
      ['Presentation', 0],
      ['Proposal Sent', 1],
      ['Invoice', 0],
      ['Lost', 0]
    ]);

    var options = {
      is3D: true,
      colors: ['#f00630', '#f2478f', '#170303', '#7cb342', '#fe0725']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);        
  }
```

Here is the script I have tried in model page

```
 public function getAllStatus()
 {
    $this->db->select('status');
    $this->db->from('sales');
    $this->db->join('sales_status', 'sales_status.id = sales.status');
    $this->db->where('sales_id', $id);
    return $query = $this->db->get();
 }
```

Here's script in `controller` page

```
 $data['sales'] = $this->Sales_model->getAllStatus()->result();
```

And here's the script in `view` page

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Type', 'Total'],
      <?php 
         foreach ($sales as $sale){
         echo "['".$sale->name."',".$sale->count."],";
         }
         ?>
    ]);

 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; "></div>
```

Do you know where's I need to fix ?

Thank you

Comment: your query does not give any error ?

Comment: it's just show `no data` in pie chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart expects JSON objects with the data. You can try to build JSON-like structures with loops like you did, but it's much simpler to just output the JSON objects.

In your view, before the call to the chart is made:

```
var first_data = <?php echo json_encode($your_first_var); ?>;
var second_data = <?php echo json_encode($your_second_var); ?>;
```

then, when you actually invoke the JS that will draw the chart:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(first_data);

    var options = {
      is3D: true,
      colors: second_data
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);        
  }
```